# Sort Attribute Option Collection

Tags: attributes, dropdown-attribute, attribute-options

I'm getting so mad that it literally hurts with a problem related to attribute option collection on Magento 1.8.1
I have a dropdown type attribute populated with dozens of values and frequently updated with new values, wich is used for layered navigation purposes.
What im trying to do is actually change de default behaviour and sort NUMERICALLY all theese options if "position" is not set.

Magento sorts my values like this (alphabetically)

> 100 Watt
>   1000 Watt
>   1200 Watt
>   200 Watt
>   300 Watt

I need to sort them this way

> 100 Watt
>   200 Watt
>   300 Watt
>   1000 Watt
>   1200 Watt

I tried to edit class **Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection** in any way.
Maybe i'm pretty close adding in public function setStoreFilter

```
    $this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $this->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("CAST('value' AS SIGNED) ASC"));
```

Hope someone can help me understand how to achieve this.

Comment: I think you're not too far from the truth with the `CAST`. Although you would probably need to strip the "Watt" text with `REPLACE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace before you try to cast it.

Comment: Maybe try the sorting with LPAD: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21156/sort-a-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql

Comment: nope, my best guess is it's overwritten * somewhere * to sort in another way so try to reset and add your sort as low in the code as possible (meaning near where it's used to output the list)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answers.
I think REPLACE and LPAD are both good for my case, but the code i posted doesn't affect the output of the attribute option collection.

Comment: Building on @SanderMangel and OP's last comment, have a look at this answer which copes with the issue of multiple sort order overrides: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/146643/22860

Comment: @pong very nice! +1

Comment: @SanderMangel I think you're right.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use the position / order column in the edit attribute form in backend? Why not set the sort order preference there

Comment: I want to implement this as default behaviour, as i have many attributes where new values are added quite frequently.